# Is socket unique?

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi

Winapi SOCKET is 32 bit integer or 64 bit integer (depends on Windows) so I want to use it as ID for client (in client - server application). My question - Is socket, casted on integer, a unique integer value?

Comment: Only at the server side IMHO. You shouldn't do any implications on the client side about it.

Comment: How could it be not unique? If there were duplicates the OS couldn't tell different sockets (in a single process) apart. Neither could you.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean at all. By unique do you mean only appears in that one place in the world? Or in that one process? At that instant? For the life of the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question - Is socket, casted on integer, a unique integer value?

It's unique to the process it's running in.

However you need to consider the possibility that the same client may have more than one connection open to you. Possibly you are looking for `getpeername()`?

Comment: I will use it as a client ID on server-side(for connected clients). So I only need uniqueness in server process. I think socket casted on integer will be enough to indentify user. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Only if there is only one user with one connection per client IP address.